# Thread blocked when using Infinispan 9 embedded cache with L1

Tags: java, infinispan, infinispan-9

I'm using Infinispan 9.4.16 in embedded mode. Here is the config of a cache:

```
<distributed-cache name="mycache" mode="SYNC" remote-timeout="15000" l1-lifespan="60000" owners="1" segments="80">
    <locking striping="false" concurrency-level="100" acquire-timeout="60000"/>
    <persistence>
        ...
    </persistence>
    <state-transfer chunk-size="512" timeout="240000"/>
</distributed-cache>
```

I run a cluster of 4 nodes. The entries in this cache could be read, updated or removed concurrently.
So randomly, a thread got blocked (waiting indefinitely) with this stack trace:

```
"a-thread-1" #403 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000023acf800 nid=0x5257 waiting on condition [0x00007fc801941000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x000000066c879658> (a org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.L1WriteSynchronizer$L1WriteSync)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:997)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.L1WriteSynchronizer$L1WriteSync.innerGet(L1WriteSynchronizer.java:93)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.L1WriteSynchronizer.get(L1WriteSynchronizer.java:142)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.L1NonTxInterceptor.abortL1UpdateOrWait(L1NonTxInterceptor.java:335)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.L1NonTxInterceptor.removeFromL1Command(L1NonTxInterceptor.java:405)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.L1NonTxInterceptor.lambda$handleDataWriteCommand$10(L1NonTxInterceptor.java:382)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.L1NonTxInterceptor$$Lambda$1347/746020467.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.SimpleAsyncInvocationStage.addCallback(SimpleAsyncInvocationStage.java:70)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationStage.andHandle(InvocationStage.java:65)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNextAndHandle(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:190)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.L1NonTxInterceptor.handleDataWriteCommand(L1NonTxInterceptor.java:362)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.L1NonTxInterceptor.visitRemoveCommand(L1NonTxInterceptor.java:247)
    at org.infinispan.commands.Visitor.visitRemoveExpiredCommand(Visitor.java:66)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.RemoveExpiredCommand.acceptVisitor(RemoveExpiredCommand.java:63)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNextThenApply(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:74)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.DistCacheWriterInterceptor.visitRemoveCommand(DistCacheWriterInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.infinispan.commands.Visitor.visitRemoveExpiredCommand(Visitor.java:66)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.RemoveExpiredCommand.acceptVisitor(RemoveExpiredCommand.java:63)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNext(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.CacheLoaderInterceptor.visitDataCommand(CacheLoaderInterceptor.java:197)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.CacheLoaderInterceptor.visitRemoveCommand(CacheLoaderInterceptor.java:164)
    at org.infinispan.commands.Visitor.visitRemoveExpiredCommand(Visitor.java:66)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.RemoveExpiredCommand.acceptVisitor(RemoveExpiredCommand.java:63)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNextThenAccept(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.EntryWrappingInterceptor.setSkipRemoteGetsAndInvokeNextForDataCommand(EntryWrappingInterceptor.java:671)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.EntryWrappingInterceptor.visitRemoveExpiredCommand(EntryWrappingInterceptor.java:363)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.RemoveExpiredCommand.acceptVisitor(RemoveExpiredCommand.java:63)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNextThenApply(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:74)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.L1LastChanceInterceptor.visitDataWriteCommand(L1LastChanceInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.L1LastChanceInterceptor.visitRemoveCommand(L1LastChanceInterceptor.java:82)
    at org.infinispan.commands.Visitor.visitRemoveExpiredCommand(Visitor.java:66)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.RemoveExpiredCommand.acceptVisitor(RemoveExpiredCommand.java:63)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNext(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractLockingInterceptor.visitNonTxDataWriteCommand(AbstractLockingInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.NonTransactionalLockingInterceptor.visitDataWriteCommand(NonTransactionalLockingInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractLockingInterceptor.visitRemoveCommand(AbstractLockingInterceptor.java:102)
    at org.infinispan.commands.Visitor.visitRemoveExpiredCommand(Visitor.java:66)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.RemoveExpiredCommand.acceptVisitor(RemoveExpiredCommand.java:63)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNextAndHandle(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:183)
    at org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferInterceptor.handleNonTxWriteCommand(StateTransferInterceptor.java:309)
    at org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferInterceptor.handleWriteCommand(StateTransferInterceptor.java:252)
    at org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferInterceptor.visitRemoveCommand(StateTransferInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.infinispan.commands.Visitor.visitRemoveExpiredCommand(Visitor.java:66)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.RemoveExpiredCommand.acceptVisitor(RemoveExpiredCommand.java:63)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNextAndFinally(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:150)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.CacheMgmtInterceptor.visitRemoveCommand(CacheMgmtInterceptor.java:431)
    at org.infinispan.commands.Visitor.visitRemoveExpiredCommand(Visitor.java:66)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.RemoveExpiredCommand.acceptVisitor(RemoveExpiredCommand.java:63)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNext(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.IsMarshallableInterceptor.visitRemoveCommand(IsMarshallableInterceptor.java:63)
    at org.infinispan.commands.Visitor.visitRemoveExpiredCommand(Visitor.java:66)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.RemoveExpiredCommand.acceptVisitor(RemoveExpiredCommand.java:63)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNext(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.DDAsyncInterceptor.handleDefault(DDAsyncInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.DDAsyncInterceptor.visitRemoveCommand(DDAsyncInterceptor.java:65)
    at org.infinispan.commands.Visitor.visitRemoveExpiredCommand(Visitor.java:66)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.RemoveExpiredCommand.acceptVisitor(RemoveExpiredCommand.java:63)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNextAndExceptionally(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.InvocationContextInterceptor.visitCommand(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNext(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.DDAsyncInterceptor.handleDefault(DDAsyncInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.DDAsyncInterceptor.visitRemoveCommand(DDAsyncInterceptor.java:65)
    at org.infinispan.commands.Visitor.visitRemoveExpiredCommand(Visitor.java:66)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.RemoveExpiredCommand.acceptVisitor(RemoveExpiredCommand.java:63)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.DDAsyncInterceptor.visitCommand(DDAsyncInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.AsyncInterceptorChainImpl.invokeAsync(AsyncInterceptorChainImpl.java:234)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.executeCommandAndCommitIfNeededAsync(CacheImpl.java:1930)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.performRemoveExpiredCommand(CacheImpl.java:717)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.removeLifespanExpired(CacheImpl.java:698)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.removeLifespanExpired(CacheImpl.java:690)
    at org.infinispan.expiration.impl.ClusterExpirationManager.handleLifespanExpireEntry(ClusterExpirationManager.java:143)
    at org.infinispan.expiration.impl.ClusterExpirationManager.entryExpiredInMemory(ClusterExpirationManager.java:201)
    at org.infinispan.container.impl.AbstractInternalDataContainer.containsKey(AbstractInternalDataContainer.java:168)
    at org.infinispan.container.impl.AbstractInternalDataContainer.containsKey(AbstractInternalDataContainer.java:178)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.L1WriteSynchronizer.runL1UpdateIfPossible(L1WriteSynchronizer.java:173)
    at org.infinispan.distribution.impl.L1ManagerImpl.remoteValueFound(L1ManagerImpl.java:196)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.BaseDistributionInterceptor.lambda$remoteGetSingleKey$1(BaseDistributionInterceptor.java:211)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.BaseDistributionInterceptor$$Lambda$1388/1407890021.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAccept(CompletableFuture.java:670)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptStage(CompletableFuture.java:683)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenAccept(CompletableFuture.java:2010)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenAccept(CompletableFuture.java:110)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.BaseDistributionInterceptor.remoteGetSingleKey(BaseDistributionInterceptor.java:200)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.BaseDistributionInterceptor.visitGetCommand(BaseDistributionInterceptor.java:666)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.BaseDistributionInterceptor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(BaseDistributionInterceptor.java:672)
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:39)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNextAndFinally(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:150)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.L1NonTxInterceptor.performL1Lookup(L1NonTxInterceptor.java:157)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.L1NonTxInterceptor.performCommandWithL1WriteIfAble(L1NonTxInterceptor.java:132)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.L1NonTxInterceptor.visitDataReadCommand(L1NonTxInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.L1NonTxInterceptor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(L1NonTxInterceptor.java:112)
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:39)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNext(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.DDAsyncInterceptor.handleDefault(DDAsyncInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.DDAsyncInterceptor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(DDAsyncInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:39)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNext(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.CacheLoaderInterceptor.visitDataCommand(CacheLoaderInterceptor.java:197)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.CacheLoaderInterceptor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(CacheLoaderInterceptor.java:130)
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:39)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNextThenAccept(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.EntryWrappingInterceptor.visitDataReadCommand(EntryWrappingInterceptor.java:204)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.EntryWrappingInterceptor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(EntryWrappingInterceptor.java:192)
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:39)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNext(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.DDAsyncInterceptor.handleDefault(DDAsyncInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.DDAsyncInterceptor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(DDAsyncInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:39)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNext(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.NonTransactionalLockingInterceptor.visitDataReadCommand(NonTransactionalLockingInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractLockingInterceptor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(AbstractLockingInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:39)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNextAndHandle(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:183)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.BaseStateTransferInterceptor.handleReadCommand(BaseStateTransferInterceptor.java:193)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.BaseStateTransferInterceptor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(BaseStateTransferInterceptor.java:168)
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:39)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNextAndFinally(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:150)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.CacheMgmtInterceptor.visitDataReadCommand(CacheMgmtInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.CacheMgmtInterceptor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(CacheMgmtInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:39)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNext(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.DDAsyncInterceptor.handleDefault(DDAsyncInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.DDAsyncInterceptor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(DDAsyncInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:39)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNext(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.DDAsyncInterceptor.handleDefault(DDAsyncInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.DDAsyncInterceptor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(DDAsyncInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:39)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNextAndExceptionally(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.InvocationContextInterceptor.visitCommand(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNext(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.DDAsyncInterceptor.handleDefault(DDAsyncInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.DDAsyncInterceptor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(DDAsyncInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:39)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.DDAsyncInterceptor.visitCommand(DDAsyncInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.AsyncInterceptorChainImpl.invoke(AsyncInterceptorChainImpl.java:248)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.get(CacheImpl.java:527)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.get(CacheImpl.java:520)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.AbstractDelegatingCache.get(AbstractDelegatingCache.java:438)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.EncoderCache.get(EncoderCache.java:660)
```

After some investigation, I found out that the thread is blocked by itself. But I don't know how it is possible. Is this an issue of Infinispan ?

Comment: 1) Thread cannot deadlock itself
2) Your stack trace is not deadlocked, it is just waiting on some condition

Comment: "parking to wait for  <0x000000066c879658" means waiting for this lock, you can take full thread dump and check which thread is holding it. Probably, it will give you some clue

Comment: I'm sorry, I must not say "deadlock" here, I edited my question. The problem is the thread is waiting for something that will never be done, because the thread is blocked when doing this thing. This is what I understand from the code.

Comment: it cannot write because smth holds the write lock.

Comment: Yes, the lock is hold by the thread itself, at the line L1WriteSynchronizer.runL1UpdateIfPossible(L1WriteSynchronizer.java:173)

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace it appears that the entry had expired via lifespan expiration at the same time. I would suggest logging a JIRA to https://issues.redhat.com/projects/ISPN. This seems to be an unexpected interaction between expiration and L1 usage.

I am assuming you must be using the programmatic method with lifespan when inserting values as well, since your configuration does not have expiration enabled.

Comment: I noticed that somehow the entry expired but I don't use expiration at all so I really don't understand why it happened.

Comment: You're using expiration indirectly, L1 entries automatically expire after 10 minutes. Setting the L1 lifespan to -1 should disable the expiration.

Comment: If I disable the expiration, the entries will stay forever in the L1 and occupy memory ?

Comment: They will only stay in L1 as long as the entry is not changed. Also if you enable eviction that will clear out old unused L1 entries.